# Header column datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to create a datagrid with the following header

```
ID  Name  Key  Unique  Null  Value  Type
----------------------------------------
```

Right now I have two classes: `dynamicentity` and `newproperty`.

`dynamicentity` is as follows

```
    private int ID;
    private string entityName;
    private string Entitydescription;
    private List<NewProperty> addedProperties;

    public DynEntity(string name, string desc)
    {
        entityName = name;
        Entitydescription = desc;
        addedProperties = new List<NewProperty>();
    }

    public bool addNP(NewProperty data)
    {
        addedProperties.Add(data);
        return true;
    }
```

My `newproperty` class is as follows

```
    private int ID;
    private string PropertyName;
    private string StringPropertie;
    private bool isString;
    private int IntPropertie;
    private bool isInt;
    private float floatPropertie;
    private bool isFloat;
    private DateTime DatetimePropertie;
    private bool isDate;
    private bool boolPropertie;
    private bool isBool;
    private bool isKey;
    private bool allowNull;
    private bool isFK;
    private string FKEntityName;
    private bool isUnique;
    public NewProperty(int _id, string _propertyname, bool propType, bool key, bool isnull, bool isunic, string fkname)
    {
        ID = _id;
        PropertyName = _propertyname;
        boolPropertie = propType;
        isInt = false;
        isString = false;
        isFloat = false;
        isDate = false;
        isBool = true;
        isKey = key;
        allowNull = isnull;
        isUnique = isunic;
        if (fkname == "")
        {
            isFK = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isFK = true;
            FKEntityName = fkname;
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("ID")]
    public int PropID
    {
        get { return ID; }
        set
        {
            ID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string PropName
    {
        get { return PropertyName; }
        set
        {
            PropertyName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
```

My xaml is as follow

```
<DataGrid Name="dgUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding DEPropID}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1">                          </DataGrid>
```

My viewmodel is:

```
private DynEntity _localDE;

        public DynEntityViewModel(DynEntity DynamicEntity)
        {
            _localDE = DynamicEntity;
        }

        public string DEName
        {
            get
            {
                return _localDE.EntityName;
            }
            set
            {
                _localDE.EntityName = value;
            }
        }

        public string DEDesc
        {
            get { return _localDE.EntityDescription; }
            set
            {
                _localDE.EntityDescription = value;
            }
        }

        public List<NewProperty> DEPropID
        {
            get { return _localDE.EntityProperties; }
        }

        public String Name
        {
            get { return _localDE.EntityProperties[0].PropName; }
        }
```

When returning a list of `newproperty` is there a way for me to modify the display header on the datagrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the header text property to a ViewModel property to change it dynamically or simply add DataGridTextColumn with text header you want:

something like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding DEPropID}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1"> 
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="YourText" Width="*" Binding="{Binding YourProperty}"/>    
      </DataGrid.Columns>                   
</DataGrid>
```

OR

```
<DataGrid Name="dgUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding DEPropID}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1"> 
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding DataContext.YourStringProperty}" Width="*" Binding="{Binding YourProperty}"/>                       
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```